# How to get 10 of the best-seller-selling products in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

hello i have this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
       title                       = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('title'))
       count_sold                  = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_('count sold'))

       def __str__(self):
             return self.title
```

How to get 10 of the best-seller-selling products  based on the number of sales(count_sold) with query ? 
thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: i don't know how to write a query for rest api.

Comment: how to get best-seller-selling products?

Comment: thanks, I thought should use of group_by().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.objects.all().order_by('-count_sold')[:10]
```

would give you the 10 most sold Products. 
With

```
order_by()
```

you can decide how the resulting querydict is ordered, for example:

```
 Product.objects.all().order_by('count_sold')[:10]
```

would give you the 10 least sold products.

Comment: Sortings and conclusions are mismatched/reversed.